# How to write to Hasura from Gatsby?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, hasura

I've discovered **Hasura** a few days ago, I've been reading the documentation to try and get familiar with *Actions*, *Subscriptions*, and general *Queries*.

I'm also new to **Gatsby** but I've managed (with some help from a lot of tutorials) to build a small project that takes data from **Hasura** and displays it using **Gatsby**.

But one thing I really want to know is how to set up data *mutations* from **Gatsby** to **Hasura**.

For example: add a blog post creation tool inside the Gatsby project so a user can create custom posts and those posts are added to the Hasura database, so I'm able to query them later.

Comment: This seems like a very broad query, what exactly are you struggling with here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61887380/how-to-write-to-hasura-from-gatsby#comment109461204_61887380), this is a very broad question, but having integrated Gatsby and Hasura a few times, I can give some pointers.

Let's start with the basics:

- [Hasura](https://hasura.io/) is basically a database that you can interact with via a GraphQL layer. it's normally used for simple CRUD operations where little server-side logic is necessary (although it's definitely [possible](https://hasura.io/learn/graphql/hasura/custom-business-logic/) to implement more complex logic).
- [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/) is a static site generator written in React. Gatsby apps have [hybrid data fetching](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/data-fetching/): some data can be fetched at build time to generate static pages, but other data can also be fetched client-side, just like in any React app.

The scenario you're describing implies both client-side and server-side operations:

> add a blog post creation tool inside the Gatsby project so a user can create custom posts and those posts are added to the Hasura database [...]

This will happen client-side, because you need user input.

> [...] so I'm able to query them later

This could be done both client-side and server-side. If you can afford to wait for your site to rebuild, the Gatsby way of doing things is to query these at build time.

## Client runtime data fetching with Gatsby

I'll say a bit more about client-side data fetching, because your question mentions that:

> one thing I really want to know is how to set up data mutations from Gatsby to Hasura

There is no built-in way to do GraphQL mutations client-side in Gatsby. Gatsby GraphQL is only used at build time.

However, as mentioned above, a Gatsby app is essentially a React app: you can fetch data just like you would in a React project. Here's an example showcasing both build time and runtime data fetching:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import { graphql, useStaticQuery } from "gatsby"
const IndexPage = () => {
  // Build Time Data Fetching
  const gatsbyRepoData = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query {
      github {
        repository(name: "gatsby", owner: "gatsbyjs") {
          id
          nameWithOwner
          url
        }
      }
    }
  `)
  // Client-side Runtime Data Fetching
  const [starsCount, setStarsCount] = useState(0)
  useEffect(() => {
    // get data from GitHub api
    fetch(`https://api.github.com/repos/gatsbyjs/gatsby`)
      .then(response => response.json()) // parse JSON from request
      .then(resultData => {
        setStarsCount(resultData.stargazers_count)
      }) // set data for the number of stars
  }, [])
  return (
    <section>
      <p>
        Build Time Data: Gatsby repo{` `}
        <a href={gatsbyRepoData.github.repository.url}>
          {gatsbyRepoData.github.repository.nameWithOwner}
        </a>
      </p>
      <p>Runtime Data: Star count for the Gatsby repo {starsCount}</p>
    </section>
  )
}
export default IndexPage
```

(source: [Fetching data at client-side runtime](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/data-fetching/#fetching-data-at-client-side-runtime))

## Client-side data fetching with GraphQL

The example above uses the browser's [`fetch` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), but as mentioned above, a benefit of Hasura is that is exposes a GraphQL endpoint.

So how can you use GraphQL for client-side queries and mutations?

A common way to achieve this in React apps is to use [Apollo](https://www.apollographql.com/). And because Gatsby is a React app, you can naturally use it too!

AI suggest starting by reading Apollo Client's [Get started guide](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/get-started/). For a Gatsby-specific implementation, take a look at Jason Lengstorf's [Gatsby with Apollo](https://github.com/jlengstorf/gatsby-with-apollo) example.

Have fun building with Gatsby, Apollo and Hasura!

Comment: I should've made my question more specific but I really didn't know how to explain what I was looking for, but this answer is perfect so I'm going to follow your advice and check out Apollo!